# Make SQL Server understand there are no cycles

Tags: sql-server, triggers, cascade, database-trigger, cascading-deletes

I have 2 tables, a simple test, which represent a real use case I need for my real application. I made it as simple as possible to find out what the appropiate solution would be.

These 2 tables are linked via foreign keys, in which the second table relates 2 instances of the objects declared in first table.

Here is the SQL Server commands to create them

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[test_cycles2]
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[test_cycles1]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test_cycles1](
  [id_cycle] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [name] [varchar](100) NULL
  PRIMARY KEY([id_cycle])
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[test_cycles1] (name) VALUES ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D');


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test_cycles2](
  [id_cycle1] [int] NOT NULL,
  [id_cycle2] [int] NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY ([id_cycle1],[id_cycle2]),
CONSTRAINT c_unique CHECK ([id_cycle1] <> [id_cycle2]),
CONSTRAINT fk_cycles2_1 FOREIGN KEY (id_cycle1) REFERENCES [dbo].[test_cycles1] (id_cycle) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT fk_cycles2_2 FOREIGN KEY (id_cycle2) REFERENCES [dbo].[test_cycles1] (id_cycle) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[test_cycles2] VALUES (1,2), (1,3), (2,4);

SELECT * FROM test_cycles1;
SELECT * FROM test_cycles2;

DELETE FROM test_cycles1 WHERE name = 'A';

SELECT * FROM test_cycles1;
SELECT * FROM test_cycles2;
```

As you can see, with the inserts I've done, for example:

Table [test_cycles2], is linking object 'A', with object 'B' --> (INSERT VALUES 1,2).

Obviously, doesn't matter if I delete 'A' or 'B' from [test_cycles1], in both cases, [test_cycles2] needs to delete on cascade, since 'A' won't be linked to 'B' anymore.

I understand SQL Server tells me there is a **possible** cycle (which I tried to **prevent** by checking in a constraint that 'A' can not be linked to 'A')

> CONSTRAINT c_unique CHECK ([id_cycle1] <> [id_cycle2])

The only solution I do find possible, is to create triggers and do this job for me. However, I am wondering if it **is actually the correct solution**? Is there no way to tell SQL Server **there won't be cycles**, since they will never share the same object both columns?

Comment: You're focussing on the wrong part of the error message - "multiple cascade paths" is the problem here, because there's one path test_cycles2 -> id_cycle1 -> test_cycles1 and another test_cycles2 -> id_cycle2 -> test_cycles1.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thats what I tried to fix with that constraint, and what I am asking for. If id_cycle1 <> id_cycle2, it can never try to delete same row on [test_cycles1]

Comment: No, you're not guaranteeing that, say, `A` is always referenced by `id_cycle1` and never by `id_cycle2` across *all rows*. So during the cascade, it would have to be trying to match on *either* of those columns. And the cascade will never delete from `test_cycles1` anyway - that's not how the cascade works.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever So that means there is no way to achieve that either the element is linked by the first column, or the second column, it gets deleted on cascade on both cases? :/